# Como retornar aviso em uma View caso não existam dados para serem exibidos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Criei o código abaixo que gera uma lista. O mesmo verifica se a lista contém algum dado gravado nela ou não. Caso tenha dados, retorna uma View com a lista dentro, caso não tenha dados, retorna `null`.

Como fazer para, ao invés de retornar `null`, mostrar um aviso na própria página informando que não existem dados para serem mostrados?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Relatorio(string ocupacaoId, string instrumentoRegistroId)
    {
        List<ProcedimentoOcupacaoRegistro> listaprocedimentoocupacaoregistro = new ProcedimentoOcupacaoRegistro().listaProcedimentoOcupacaoRegistro(ocupacaoId, instrumentoRegistroId);
        ViewBag.ocupacaoId = ocupacaoId;
        ViewBag.instrumentoregistroId = instrumentoRegistroId;
        if (listaprocedimentoocupacaoregistro.Count > 0)
        {
            return View(listaprocedimentoocupacaoregistro)
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // <<---AQUI EU QUERO ALTERAR
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que queira isto:

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.emptyresult?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

A [documentação da classe `ActionResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) mostra todos os tipos de retorno possível para a *view*. É possível inclusive criar outras que atendem melhor sua necessidade.

Tem outras formas.

Pelo que eu vi o `null` acaba dando o mesmo resultado.

Aí você tem que tratar na *view* como lidar com esta situação. Pode enviar para a *view* normal e tratar lá como apresentar para o usuário, algo assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProcedimentoOcupacaoRegistro>

@if (Model.Count() > 0) {
    ...
} else {
    <div>Não tem itens pra mostrar</div>
}
```

Ou, o que é mais comum, enviar uma *view* diferente que mostra a mensagem de erro que você deseja, afinal mostrar os dados é uma visão, mostrar que não tem dados para mostrar é outra visão, exemplo:

```
return RedirectToAction("Error", "Relatorio");
```

Dependendo de como está montado pode enviar código:

```
return JavaScript( "alert('Nada a mostrar');" );
```

Ou ainda:

```
return View("SemDadosView");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/NoDataView.cs).

Claro que precisa criar a *view* do jeito que deseja.